# Is it possible to specify individual fonts in Flex DropDownList?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, drop-down-menu, flex4

I have just implemented a dropdownlist of checkboxes taken from this [ComboCheck example](http://www.carballares.es/en/arcadio/?p=555) but made it extend `DropDownList` instead of `ComboBox` to provide better functionality that I required. I am attempting to create a `DropDownList` where some items are **bold** and non-checkboxes (or can be checkboxes) and others are not.

I have not been able to find anything online about doing this yet and have been trying to figure it out. I am currently using an `ArrayCollection` as a `dataProvider` but I think this could possibly be my issue and I should be trying to setup the labels in flex not AS3.

Does anyone know if this is possible? And if so do they have any links that could possibly help point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Code added for the itemRenderer, this worked I just need to specify each item that I want to be bold, though is there a better way to do this in the flex code as opposed to checking for a matching string in the renderer?

```
public class ComboCheckItemRenderer extends ItemRenderer{  
    public var item:CheckBox;  

    public function ComboCheckItemRenderer(){
        super();
        item = new CheckBox();
        item.x = 5;
        addElement(item);
        item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
    }

    private var _data:Object;
    [Bindable]override public function set data (value:Object):void {
        if (value!=null) {
            _data = value;
            item.label = value.label;
            if(item.label == "item1"){
                item.setStyle("color","0x00ff00");
                item.setStyle("fontWeight","bold");
            }
            item.selected = value.selected;
        }
    }
```

**Edit 2:** What I am ultimately trying to do is create a dropdown of checkboxes with data that I obtain from blazeDS that basically has a bunch of group titles and their corresponding sub-elements. I am trying to have the dropdown make the groups be in bold and to the left, and their sub-elements normal font and offset to the right. I also need to know when they are clicked whether it was a group header or sub-element, so that I can add them to an object that I will be sending back to my service to perform a sql query on.
ie.

```
[ ]**GROUP**  
   [ ] element
   [ ] element
[ ]**GROUP**  
   [ ] element
```

Comment: Show some code; there should be no reason you can't create an itemRenderer that bolds some items, but not others.

Comment: I provided the link to the combocheck example, I am basically going entirely off that (you can view source there), just removing a couple elements I do not need. I am not sure which other code would be useful though

Comment: Although I think that may actually have been exactly what I needed, I was just able to change the colour in the itemRenderer so I know I can change the style of everything. Though is this the best way to do it and have if-statements for each element that I want bold? I will work at this for a bit to see if I can get it working correctly and post that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your data look like?  Why aren't you using MXML for this?  Why are you overriding `set data()` as opposed to hooking the `dataChange` event? You are writing way more code than you need to here.

Lets look at it in a more "Flexy" way.  Notice how I am using data binding for everything and conditionally setting the `fontWeight` based on the data that comes in.  Anything more complicated should bust out to a function in the `Script` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="true">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:CheckBox x="5" click="onClick(event)" 
                label="{data.label}" selected="@{data.selected}" 
                fontWeight="{data.label == 'item1' ? 'bold' : 'normal'}"/>


</s:ItemRenderer>
```

In light of your question you added in your edit, I would ask: What criteria are you using? You can put any function in your binding expression, so at a very minimum, you might do something like this:

```
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private var itemsToBold:Array = ["label1", "label2"];

        private function getFontWeight(label):String {
            if(itemsToBold.indexOf(label) > 0)
                return "bold";

            return "normal";
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:CheckBox fontWeight="{getFontWeight(data.label)}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will try to implement this flex functionality. I was unable to find a "Flexy" way of doing it myself so I had to turn to the example actionscript code. Please see my new edit for my actual final goal.

Comment: @Mike: That is a completely different question than what you asked, actually.  I think you want the Tree component for that... or at least create a data structure that supports that layout better.  I suggest marking this question answered and start a new question with your new requirements.

Comment: A tree does not actually seem to be what I am looking for after looking into it, I need them as checkboxes for selection (unless you can do this with a tree too?). Even the group headers as checkboxes. Though I will close it as answered but I was able to create a solution (even though its probably pretty ugly) that fit my needs

Comment: Sure, you can do this with a Tree.  You just need to skin it and set your itemRenderers appropriately.